# "Smart casual" vs. "casual chic"

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage

As far as apparel code goes, is "casual chic" just about the same as "smart casual", or is there a nuance I am missing?

Comment: Americans often use “smart” to mean well-dressed, and “smart casual” is understood to mean the blazer-and-jeans look (and similar styles).

Comment: @BraddSzonye Interesting. I don't somehow think that 'smart casual' in Britain would allow for jeans. Blazer yes; but jeans? I'm not sure. Women might get away with it, but not sure about men. I would be interested to know what others think. Perhaps it is just my age and that of my social companions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two terms are thrown about interchangeably, but can be nuanced depending upon the intent of the person making the invitation.

Smart casual means well dressed, but casual. Jeans and a blazer, would be smart casual. A button down shirt, but no tie would be smart casual.

Casual chic is often used in the same manner. But, chic carries a sense of fashion forward to it. So, they're saying *designer jeans* and a blazer.